# Is Eldia really on Madagascar?

Tags: attack-on-titan

Noticing the German names, and architecture in Eldia led me to believe that Eldia was somewhere around Europe. However, I've seen maps that theorize that it's actually located in Madagascar.

The only thing that doesn't make a lot of sense to me is that Madagascar is very tropical. In the anime, they show forests and areas that are very "taiga-like" which is a biome more reminiscent of Europe.

If you could clarify this for me, it would be awesome!

Comment: There's [an unsourced answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/61216/2516) about the map of the *Attack on Titan* universe. Assuming it's true, it's probably more likely that Eldia is on a Madagascar-like island and environment, but not real-life Madagascar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes and no

The map provided of Paradis and Marley shows that Paradis Island is northeast of the continent of Marley (it's that white island to the left of the compass)

[image: Attack on Titan world map]

But... hmm... if we take it and flip it over...

[image: Attack on Titan world map inverted]

It's hard to argue that's not a regular world map and, yes, that would make Paradis Island into to Madagascar